# Where does the inconsistency between QM and general relativity stem from?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, quantum-gravity

I understand special relativity works with QM (as seen by QFT) and I know that there is some discrepancy between GR and QM. Could someone elaborate on that? Where does the inconsistency stem from? Different formulations of the 2 theories, conceptual incompatibilities, or something else?